# Apollo and Vue3 with form input model. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-apollo

I am trying to create a web app that uses Vue3, Apollo, and the Quasar framework. I have schema structure that looks like this:

gql:

```
workout {
  id
  exercises {
    id
    name
    sets {
      id
      weight
      reps
...
```

I retrieve this in `setup()` with `useQuery` and loop through the exercises and sets to get input groups for each set. (using latest verision of https://github.com/quasarframework/app-extension-apollo)

```html
<q-input
  v-model="set.reps"
  type="number"
  hint="reps"
/>
```

And I can see the value of reps in the input! Great! But when I go to change the input I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'reps' of object '#<Object>'
```

I've read this immutability is by design to prevent buggy behavior. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Do I need to restructure the query? I would like to have a user interact with the data and be able to mutate it.  Any tips for getting to this behavior?

Comment: maybe is what you need : https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/#mutations

Comment: I've been successfully performing mutations in other places in the app. However, only where a mutation depends on a button click. It seems that apollo data doesn't like being a model for an input

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck too. I've got the same issue.

Comment: I ended up having to do a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. I wish there was a better way though